# Why is this YAD list code not working correctly?

Tags: bash, checkbox, listbox, yad

I'm trying to incorporate YAD into my script to add a more GUI feel to it.
(It may end up being written in Python at a later date.)
I'm able to use similar code to produce a listbox with selectable items in an
earlier part of the code without issue, but this bit is doing my head in.

```
x=1
for f in "${Basic_Info[@]}" ; do echo " $x $f" ; x=$(( x + 1 )) ; done 

album=$(for f in "${Basic_Info[@]}" ; do echo FALSE ; echo "$f" ; done | yad --list \
    --center --title="Album selection" --height="$hite" --width="550" --checklist \
     --column="Select" --column="Artist - Album to use:" --print-column="2" )
```

The above produces the following:-
Screen output from the echo loop
[image: Screen output from echo command]

and:
The YAD listbox output

[image]

If you cannot see the attached pictures, the problem is:-

The for loop using echo produces the correct output on the screen.

The for loop piped to the YAD list shows incorrect output.

Obviously the variable $hite changes depending upon the number of items in the
Basic_Info array, but doesn't affect the incorrect output.

Please can somebody tell me what is going on, as I'm starting to lose my mind
over this issue.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you have & character in song's names. add --no-markup option to yad or filter loop output through sed "s/&/&amp;/g"

Comment: Hi VictorAnanjevsky - welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your answer is almost there - please add a little more clarification about the problem .. e.g. something like - by default YAD treats the content as markup, so characters like & need to be quoted to be valid markup, OR yad should be run with the --no-markup option.  And you can make a small code snippet (use _```_ on a line at the start, and on a line after it) showing how to fix (because it isn't just & that needs to be considered is it??)